# OpenGL Skybox not drawn over camera

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a skybox for a simple OpenGL application that I'm working on, the cube I am drawing for the skybox does exist in the 3d space, but it isn't drawn around the camera and moves one unit to the direction the camera is moving while I move the camera and stops doing this when I stop moving the camera. The only way I have been able to get it almost working how I want it to is by making the cube really big, and I'd like to be able to get it working as a unit cube.

Thanks.

```
void Scene3D::Skybox()
{

        //glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //Translate to camera

        float skyboxSize = 1.0f; //Half width and height for skybox cube, used to add or subtract from camera position to create cube.

        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

        //-Top-\\

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        //Far left
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        //Far right
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        //Close right
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        //Close left
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        glEnd();

        //-Bottom-\\

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        //Far left;
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.25f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        //Far right
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.25f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        //Close right
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        //Close left
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        glEnd();

        //-Left-\\

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        //Top left
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        //Top right
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        //Bottom right
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        //Bottom left
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        glEnd();

        //-Front-\\

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        //Top left
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        //Top right);
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        //Bottom right
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        //Bottom left
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        glEnd();

        //-Right-\\

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        //Top left
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        //Top right
        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        //Bottom right
        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ + skyboxSize);

        //Bottom left
        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        glEnd();

        //-Back-\\

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        //Top left
        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        //Top right
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY + skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        //Bottom right
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX + skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        //Bottom left
        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(cameraPosX - skyboxSize, cameraPosY - skyboxSize, cameraPosZ - skyboxSize);

        glEnd();

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When rendering a skybox, you need to eliminate the *translation* component of the modelview matrix.  You can do this by translating by the inverse of the current translation:

```
 glPushMatrix();
 GLfloat matrix[16];  
 glGetFloatv (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
 glTranslatef(-matrix[12], -matrix[13], -matrix[14]);

 ... your code ...

 glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Not to nitpick, but I think you mean ***translation***. If you eliminated the ***transform*** you'd be left with an identity matrix ;) Also, `-matrix[15]` looks fishy, that is the `W` component of the 4th column (it should probably be `-matrix[14]`). All that aside, if you do this it will isolate the rotation / scaling component of the ModelView matrix and that should do the trick if the OP removes `cameraPos<X/Y/Z>` from the vertex positions.

Comment: @Jherico I've added what you have suggested and what is included in the other comment and it works partially, but I'm still getting something wrong. The skybox still does get drawn around the camera and it only stays in one position when I move the x position of the camera, whenever I move the camera along the y axis the skybox seems to move along the z axis and vice versa. Thanks for the help so far but I'm fair newly to OpenGL, and don't really know what I'm doing so I might be missing something obvious.